# Why am I able to call a private function in an Inherited contract on remix IDE when that's not supposed to happen?

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Base {

    function privateFunc() private pure returns (string memory) {
        return "private function called, ya dig";
    }

    function testPrivateFunc() public pure returns (string memory) {
        return privateFunc();
    }

    function internalFunc() internal pure returns (string memory) {
        return "internal function called";
    }


}

contract A is Base {
    function test() public view returns (string memory) {
        return internalFunc();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code shows a call to an `internal` function from a child contract, which is allowed (https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/types.html?highlight=internal#function-types). Is it a typo / mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`testPrivateFunc` is not a private function even though it is calling a private function.